# I found a way to calculate Quadratic min mod $N$, but why does it work?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factoring, prime-factorization

I am trying to factor $N$ using [Dixon's factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method), so I am looking at the equation:

$$a^2\equiv b(\mod{N})$$

If I am able to find $b$ that is a perfect square, I will be able to factor $N$.

While looking at the values of the following $f(x)$, I noticed something very interesting:

$$f(x)\equiv(\lceil\sqrt{N}\rceil+x)^2(\mod{N})$$

The values of $f(x)$ grow as $x$ grows, but then they fall again and start over, like waves.

Since there is a bigger chance of finding [B-smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) values when $f(x)$ is small, it is beneficial to only look at the start of the waves. I noticed that most of the time $f(x)<\sqrt{N}$ in those locations, and by experiment I found a formula to get those values.

$$f_{min}(x)=\lceil\frac{\lceil\sqrt{(a-b+1)^2+4(xN-a)}\rceil+(a-b+1)}{2}\rceil+\lceil\sqrt{N}\rceil$$

- $a = f(0)$
- $b = f(1)$

**Edit:** tnx to **Tob Ernack** that notice that $f_{min}(x)$ can be reduced to

$$f_{min}(x)=\lceil\sqrt{Nx}\rceil$$

*Note that $\mod{N}$ been removed and it still works*

$f(f_{min}(x))$ will be either the start or the end location of the wave (if it is the end, then the next value is the start)

So my question is **Why does the formula work?**

**Edit:**

Here is another interesting observation:

$f(a) < f(b)$ iff $\lceil\sqrt{Na}\rceil^2-Na<\lceil\sqrt{Nb}\rceil^2-Nb$

Here are example values:

- $N=296629285609=570043\cdot 520363$
- $\lceil\sqrt{N}\rceil=544637$
- $f(f_{min}(0)) = 176160$
- $f(f_{min}(1)+1) = 303071$
- $f(f_{min}(2)+1) = 612094$
- $f(f_{min}(3)+1) = 704640$
- $f(f_{min}(4)+1) = 15980$

Here is the java code I use to evaluate this:

```
   private BigInteger nextJump(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger index, BigInteger root) {
        BigInteger abDif = a.subtract(b).add(ONE);
        BigInteger difPower = abDif.pow(2);
        return sqrCeil(
                difPower
                        .add(V_4.multiply(N.multiply(index).subtract(a)))
        )
                .add(abDif)
                .divide(TWO).add(root);
    }

    BigInteger lastY = TWO;

    private BigInteger sqrCeil(BigInteger value) {
        BigInteger y = lastY;
        BigInteger result = value.divide(y);
        while (true) {
            BigInteger subtract = y.subtract(result);
            if (subtract.abs().equals(BigInteger.ONE) || subtract.equals(ZERO)) {
                break;
            }
            y = result.add(y).divide(TWO);
            result = value.divide(y);
        }
        lastY = y;
        return y;
    }
```

Comment: @TobErnack please simplify it then

Comment: I did not notice it's reduced modulo $N$ after that.

Comment: Are you sure that $f_{min}$ is the one you're using? Is there supposed to some modulo reduction in there? I cannot reproduce those values. Eg, I get $f(f_{min}(1)+1)=245739318596$ and $f(f_{min}(2)+1)=137670553266$.

Comment: @TobErnack Yes, you are right!

Comment: @PM2Ring I added the java code I use to generate this. I translated the formula from there. I don't think there are mistakes there.

Comment: the periodic behavior reminds me of the final stage (inverse) fourier transform step of [shors algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm), maybe some connection?