# Find the top $k$ min values of $f(x)=\lceil\sqrt{Nx}\rceil^2-Nx$

Tags: functional-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to find when the function $t(x)$ is close to the function $g(y)$, by close I mean when the $g(y)-t(x)$ are the smallest numbers. I am not searching for the minimum value, but for the top $k$ minimum values.

$$t(x) = xN$$
$$g(y)=y^2$$

- $x,y,N > 0$
- $N$ is a big value that is hard to factor

In particular I want to find what are the minimum values of $f(x)$ I believe that the answer to the above question and this question is the same

$$f(x)=\lceil\sqrt{Nx}\rceil^2-Nx$$

*This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545250/i-found-a-way-to-calculate-quadratic-min-mod-n-but-why-does-it-work)*